# Replacement for Polymer.waitingFor(...) in 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've read through the Polymer 1.0 documentation but can't find a replacement for the 0.5 helper function `Polymer.waitingFor(...)`.

Is there a replacement, or is there another approach I should follow if I need to know which elements are blocking registration for another element?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use `async(method, [wait])`
from documentation https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html

With this method you can get the items when they become available
For example

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{config}}">

<div class="cls">{{item.name}}</div>

</template>
```

And in Polymer attached function

```
attached: function() {
    this.async(function() {
        //in this method you can get all div with class 'cls'
        Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('.cls');    
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would address the problem -- what I need is the list of custom elements that have not yet finished registering at a given point in time